# Using a shared_ptr<const T> from a stored shared_ptr<T>

Tags: c++

I have some data stored using an `std::shared_ptr<T>`.

Now I want to use that that as `const` input to a function, so I need an `std::shared_ptr<const T>`. How do I do that?

Can I pass the `std::shared_ptr<T>` object to the function expecting a `std::shared_ptr<const T>`?

Comment: Have you done any research in this area?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Why do you say that? I'm neutral because I don't really knot much about it.

Comment: Hmm. Well last time I tried, that cast wasn't implemented. It appears to be implemented now. Still, shared_ptr has many other shortcomings. I believe that java-style reference counting, with a root superclass, is a better technical solution. shared_ptr's advantage is that it can wrap any class, true. But that comes at expense of doing twice as many heap allocations. Plus, one has to go through contortions to construct a smart pointer from `this`. Plus, it would be nice to be able to prove by contract that the smart ptr is not null.

Comment: Does the function need to own the pointer? Will passing the pointer to the function result in it living longer than the scope of the function call? If not then is there any reason you can't just pass the  raw pointer `const T*`?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: _"The short answer is: nope"_ If you'd posted this as an answer I'd be able to downvote it to indicate that it is wrong. Since you posted it as a comment instead, please remove it to prevent the spread of misinformation. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

**[Yes](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b50c41f422aae5f).**

```
#include <memory>

void foo(std::shared_ptr<const int> ptr) {}

int main()
{
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<int>();
    foo(ptr);
}
```

Why didn't you just try it?